# I can add and edit resources from dll compiled at runtime?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have a project webr that hosts two resource resx files in webr.properties, and resources are accessed as static properties, but when publishing the website becomes bin/webr.dll and bin/es/webr.resources.dll resx file are embedded in these dll, I can add and edit these resources in runtime in persistently?  It is not to affect other projects that keep static reference to these resources.
What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend storing the new resources you want on the file system or in a database, and accessing them that way. Modifying the resources at runtime could be in theory possible, but feels like a strange solution. If it is images you are talking about, then I would try to find out how it is recommended to serve images in the specific web framework you are using.

Comment: resources are localized strings for the current thread cultureinfo, are in a satellite project only resource access, db only stored the key for access the resource with resourcemanager.getstring(key), I can extract or access the embedded resources without affecting referencing several web applications?

Comment: If you want dynamically updating localized strings, I would create a database table that had the the key, the cultureinfo, and the value for that key and cultureinfo.

Comment: If you want to edit the resource file without having to edit the web applications that reference that resource file, then that would be quite a tricky thing to pull off. In theory it is feasible (just editing the bytes in the file) but it would be very fragile.

Answer (score 0):

No, you are referring to satellite assembly and that is precompiled and stored in your bin.

You can use other means like filesystem,database or any similar mechanism.